# How to use propertly cpp classes

Tags: c++

I wanted to use classed to organize my cpp code but it looks like I am not doing the thing properly
I created the utilities class like that in utilities.h:

```
class utilities
{
public:
QString read_text_to_file(QString name, int  nline); };
```

in utilities.cpp:

```
QString utilities::read_text_to_file(QString name, int  nline)
{
        QString line;
        QString string;
       QFile file(name);
       file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text);
       int i=1;
       while(!file.atEnd()){
           line = file.readLine();
           if(i==nline){
           string=line.simplified();
           file.close();
     //        cout<<"file line value "<<qPrintable(name)<<" "<<nline<<" "<<qPrintable(string)<<endl;
           return string;
           }
           i++;
       }
   file.close();

   return QString();

}
```

it's compiling fine.
But when I want to call the function in another routine it fails:
in routine.cpp

```
#include "utilities.h"
void operator()(OBMol *mol)
    {        QString Rootdir=utilities::read_text_to_file(inputfile,1);}
```

the error I get is / error: cannot call member function 'QString utilities::read_text_to_file(QString, int)' without object
         QString Rootdir=utilities::read_text_to_file(inputfile,1);

A precision the QString object is well defined I am using Qt library, that part is ok.

Any help?

Thanks
                                                                 ^

Comment: A (non-static) method requires an object (instance of the class) to be executed on. Like, `object.method()` or `pointer->method()`. Either make your method static or even better make it a free function, probably inside of a namespace.

Comment: You call the function like it was a non-member function, or a `static` member function, or a member of a `namespace` (which it seems like you really want).

Comment: there is no state that needs to persist between function calls, so there is no reason to put it inside a class. You could however, just as an example, write a class that takes a filename in its constructor and that has a `read_text_to_file(int nline)` method (shouldnt it be `read_text_from_file`?)

Comment: Using classes properly includes not using them at all when they serve no purpose.

Comment: @molbdnilo thanks for that usefull comment that really helped me improved my c++ skill